# Why is DataTaskWithRequest is being called last?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have to make an application that recovers data in an API, for that I use `NSURLSession.sharedSession` and `dataTaskWithRequest` with my request.

I managed to recover all the informations but I cannot understand why `dataTaskWithRequest` is called last.

```
func my_connection(login: NSString, password: NSString) -> Void {
let request: NSMutableURLRequest = create_request(login, password: password)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
print("test1")
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
    if (data == nil) {
        NSLog("Error Connection")
    }
    print("test2")
    let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!
    if (my_code_HTTP(res.statusCode) == 0) {
        var jsonData:NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
        do {
            jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
            extract_data_projets(jsonData)
            extract_data_activity(jsonData)
            extract_data_history(jsonData)
            display_board()
        }
        catch {
            NSLog("Error")
        }
        my_connection_user()
        my_connection_notes()
    }
})
print("test3")
task.resume()
print("test4")
}
```

This is what I get after compilation:

```
 test1
 test3
 test4
 test2
```

Comment: By the way, you really don't want `let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!`, because if the request failed for any reason, your app would crash. It is safer to do something like `if let res = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse { ... }`. I usually do something like `if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpResponse.statusCode == 200 { ... }`.

Comment: Yes i check this in my function "my_code_HTTP"

Comment: That's fine, but my key point is that you don't want `let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!`, because it will crash if `response` is not a `NSHTTPURLResponse` (which is very possible).

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are doing asynchronous request. Your request will be executed at min. after the `resume()`, but not immadietely after. You are doing the `task()` after the `test3` so this makes your asynchronous request last. If you did it before `test3`, and if your request would be fast as hell it could possibly be before `test4`, but you'll never know.

Comment: Thanks I understand now :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the magic of asynchronous programming: Since it is designed to happen in background(or in different thread, whatever you call it for the sake of this example) it usually has the lower priority in terms of execution time than anything that happens imperatively such as `print("test4")`

Basically, if I were to translate how your program "understand" following code

```
print("test3")
task.resume()
print("test4")
```

it would be: "print "test3", now resume the task, OK it's asynchronous one so we will call somebody else to do that for me. Now I'm printing "test4" and you will probably see "test2" in a moment because my dude is taking care of it"

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)